Problem regarding entire function and concept of sequence
Let $f$ be an entire function such that for every integer $k\geq 1$ there is an infinite set $X_k$ such that $f(z)=\frac{1}{k}$ for all $z_k \in X_k$.  which of the following are necessarily true?
a) there exists an infinite set $X$ such that $f(z) = 0$ for all $z \in X$.
b) there exists a nonempty closed set $X$ such that $f(z) =0$ for all $z\in X$.
c) the set $X_k$ is unbounded for each $k\geq 1.$
d) if there exists a bounded sequence $z_n$ such that $z_k \in X_k$ for each $k \geq 1$ , then $f$ has a zero.
This question was asked before.
OPTION A:
Here f is an entire function . If $X$ is an infinite set having limit point we can use identity theorem and the fact that $f(z) = 0$ for all $z \in X$ to show $f$ is identically zero in the entire complex plane. But it contradicts the condition that $f(z)=\frac{1}{k}$ for all $z_k \in X_k$. So we can say false. But not all infinite sets have limit point. In that case I am stuck on how to proceed further.
OPTION B: I got this option as right though it is wrong. I used inverse image of closed set is closed under continuous function. Here $f$ is continuous since it is analytic. But I don't know to prove "Non empty"
OPTION C: I am not sure if this logic is flawed. If we take atleast one $X_k$ set to be bounded , by Bolazano Weirstrass theorem it would have limit point and then by Identity theorem $f(z)=\frac{1}{k}$ throughout the entire plane which leads to contradiction as $f$ is not constant. Hence all $X_k$ are unbounded.
OPTION D: $f(z_1) = 1$, $f(z_2) = \frac{1}{2}$, $f(z_n) = \frac{1}{n}$ and so on. Since f is continuous and the sequence ${z_n}$ has limit point say $z_0$(By Bolzano Weirstrass theorem),  $\{f(z_n)\}$ converges to $f(z_0)$ . Hence $f(z_0)=0$. So Option D is true.
Kindly explain  option A and B and please check the explanation for option C and D

$f(z) = e^z$ satisfies the condition and has no zeros ...

Options a) and b) are false. Just take $f=\exp$, and, for each $k\in\Bbb N$, take $X_k=-\log(k)+2\pi i\Bbb Z$. But function $f$ has no zeros. And option c) is true, since, if $X_k$ was bounded for some $k$, it would have an accumulation point, and therefore $f$ would be constant and equal to $\frac1k$, by the identity theorem. But the $l\ne k\implies X_l=\emptyset$.
What you did for option d) is correct.
